# Регулярное выражение для поиска gps координат в строке

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Может прийти строка вида:

```
      m689км.150м. а.д Казань-Оренбург-Акбулак гр.Р.Казахстан,движение из 
      г.Оренбург,Сакмарский р-он,52.0157 55.2073689км.150м. а.д Ка
```

или:

```
      672км200м а/дКазань-Оренбург-Акбулак гр.Р.Казахстан,Октябрьский р-н,в г. Оренбург 52.1528 55.2263
```

Подскажите как составить выражение чтобы оно срабатывало, если цифр после "." больше трех.

Comment: покажите что уже получилось! Вот выбирает все цифры (если цифр более 3х) после точки`\.\d{3,}`

Comment: @JVic , String regularExpressionForDouble = "((\\d)+((\\.\\d{3,})+))";

Comment: какую строку конкретно нужно получить в результате?

Comment: @JVic , сейчас получаю [52.0157, 55.2073689] это вполне устраивает, лишнее обрежу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Больше трех цифр: `[\d]{4,}`

Полное регулярное выражение: `([\d]+\.[\d]{4,})` или `([\d]+\.[\d]{4,} [\d]+\.[\d]{4,})`.

Поиграться можно [здесь](https://regex101.com/r/ShWuWn/3).